# display a different statement when clicking on a button in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

When clicking on a button I want it to display a different style and map through an array of objects. But I can't get past the first object. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1Ani.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQDLP.png)

```
const handleHeroCard = () => {
  I am performing a findIndex function but it doesn't go past the second object in the array
}
```

Comment: please provide your `code` to elaborate more about the problem.

Comment: the code is in the links that I provided

Comment: Click on the link where it says enter image description here

Comment: You have to post the code not in form of picture. Read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#:~:text=Images%20require%20more%20bandwidth%20than,byte%20and%20every%20millisecond%20count.)

Answer (score 0):

You are using your `useState` with `[heroCard,setHeroCard]` with default value of `(page.page.data)`.

when you call the function throught the button you are again setting the hero card to be only of data of 0 index.

So,here basically your original array of data is replaced with only one data which will be of 0 index.

Your original array of data is permanently replaced unless you restore it through your fetching mechanism.

In order to get solution you can use two variables.

one to store original array of data.

another to get the desired data from original array.

Comment: I apologize I would like to map through the array and display the title or document based on the index not display a certain style. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Two identical objects are never equal. You are trying to compare two objects using `findIndex`. This is a mistake.

Just `return card` variable after your `console.log` in `handleHeroCards`.

```js
const Hero = () => {
const [cards, setCards] = useState(data.data.pages[0]);
const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
const [heroCard, setHeroCard] = useState(cards[0]);
 
const handleHeroCards = (value) => {
  let index = activeIndex + value;
  if (index < 0) index = 0;
  if (index > cards.length) index = cards.length;
  setActiveIndex(index);
  setHeroCard(cards[index])
}
...

<button onClick={()=> handleHeroCards(-1)}>&lt;</button>
<button onClick={()=> handleHeroCards(1)}>&gt;</button>
}
```